# Why can't people see colors in "The Giver"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-giver

In *The Giver (2014)*, it is a world where people lack feelings.

Why was the ability to see in color taken away?

Comment: ["even the memory of these things has been given up to assure security and conformity (called Sameness)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver).

Comment: How is this unclear? What about this question doesn't make sense? It wasn't asked particularly well but it's not unclear - if you've seen the film or read the books, it is obvious what the question is asking.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie but "Sameness" seems to be the ideal referenced in the base novel. Plus colors do create/project emotions or at least have an emotional component so that would seem to be another factor.

Comment: I would suspect because colour helps evoke emotion. The concept is touched on in Equilibrium and Pleasantville.

Answer (score 4):

**The Giver** states that the choice of color was taken away to prevent people from making the wrong choices. The idea of the society they live in is to maintain conformity, where society is stripped of things that can cause conflict to arise between others.  Even a simple thing, such as picking a shirt in the morning, causes Jonas a little conflict, but even he can see the far reaching implications.